# Mysql: Update values of one column with values from multiple colums

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are about 12 tables in my DB with many columns. I would like to pick information I need from them and put it into a new table with a pre-defined structure. All tables have an unique identifier "ID".

newtable structure:

> ID | apples | bananas | cucumbers | dates

table1 structure

> ID | chiquita | grannysmith | IDontWanthis | OrThis

Using:

```
UPDATE newtable SET bananas = (SELECT chiquita FROM table1
                               WHERE newtable.ID = table1.ID)
```

I have however difficulties when more columns can hold the piece of information I need to fill in the new column.

I tried:

```
UPDATE newtable SET apples = (SELECT grannysmith FROM table1
                              WHERE newtable.ID = table1.ID)
```

and then a new update:

```
UPDATE newtable SET apples = (SELECT elstar FROM table2
                              WHERE newtable.ID = table2.ID
                              AND newtable.apples IS NULL)
```

It however replaces all the values in newtable.apples with table2.elstar, not only the NULL values. The values that were filled in previously are now NULL.

I'm very new to SQL and don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Is there maybe a more efficient way to do this?
Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE newtable SET apples = (SELECT elstar FROM table2
                          WHERE newtable.ID = table2.ID
                          AND newtable.apples IS NULL)
WHERE apples IS NULL
```

You need a `where` clause to filter for `apples is null` in the outer query as well.

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick! Could you elaborate please? What is the logic behind the second "WHERE"?

Comment: the reason is that the outer query doesn't know which rows to update with out a `where` condition. Hence you have to specify `where` in the outer query as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `JOIN`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3dda/1

```
UPDATE newtable n
INNER JOIN table1 t
ON n.id = t.id
SET n.bananas = t.chiquita, n.apples = t.grannysmith
```

and if you want to avoid overwrite old value in `newtable` you can change `ON` clause like:

```
UPDATE newtable n
INNER JOIN table1 t
ON n.id = t.id AND (n.bananas IS NULL OR n.apples IS NULL)
SET n.bananas = t.chiquita, n.apples = t.grannysmith
```

**UPDATE** Even if you want to update just one column per time `JOIN` is more preferable way to do that from preformance perspective:

```
UPDATE newtable n
INNER JOIN table1 t
ON n.id = t.id AND n.bananas IS NULL 
SET n.bananas = t.chiquita
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I need to update one column from multiple tables (= perform multiple joins). The last table will re-write the rest.

Comment: Multiple `JOINs` does work.  You specify which table(s) to change.